# Azure SQL output binding for Azure Functions will not insert row in database

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am following this guide to create a binding to update my database: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-output?tabs=csharp

I feel like I have done everything the guide says, however I am still getting an error.

The error is:

```
[2022-03-10T20:39:31.466Z] Executed 'PostFileInformationByDeviceId' (Failed, Id=d0cecd1b-e54b-4716-9cfc-921bb6f458ac, Duration=701ms)
[2022-03-10T20:39:31.467Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: PostFileInformationByDeviceId. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while handling parameter newItem after function returned:. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Sql: Encountered error(s) while parsing schema and object name: Incorrect syntax near ..
```

The function code is the following:

```
[FunctionName("PostFileInformationByDeviceId")]
public static IActionResult Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "postFile/{deviceId}")]
HttpRequest req, [Sql("dbo.File", ConnectionStringSetting = "SqlConnectionString")] out FileInformation newItem,
    ILogger log)
{
    newItem = new FileInformation
    {
Hash = "hash",
DeviceId = "deviceid"
    };

    return new OkResult();
}
```

This is my model:

```
public class FileInformation
{
public string Hash { get; set; }

public string UserId { get; set; }

public string DeviceId { get; set; }

public int Timestamp { get; set; }

public string Filename { get; set; }

public int Filetype { get; set; }
}
```

My database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[File] (
[Hash]      VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
[Timestamp] INT          NULL,
[DeviceId]  NCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
[UserId]    NCHAR (10)   NULL,
[Filename]  NCHAR (10)   NULL,
[Filetype]  INT          NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Hash] ASC)
);
```

I purposley set the DB fields to NOT NULL so I could easily test the insert functions with just to values

ANY help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"File" is a reserved word in T-SQL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Try naming your table something that's not a reserved word - "dbo.MyFile", perhaps.